# How can I externalize my Shopify cli app into a custom url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify-app, shopify-api

I create a Shopify App (with Shopify CLI)

I would like this app to be "external" and open in a new tab, with a custom URL.

The goal is that different sellers in my Shopify store can use it (upload products, manage their orders, etc.)

I would like to point out that I have already activated the "new tab" option in Shopify Partner.
But it loop loads my page for me and still shows my app in Shopify admin.

Comment: You will need to host your app on a separate server and provide a URL to access it. You can check Heroku, AWS or GCP